# Matrix exponential of nonsingular matrix, diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, matrix-exponential

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and be nonsingular. Is $e^A$ (matrix exponential) diagonalizable?
Can you prove it?

If not correct, what are the conditions for $A$ so that $e^A$ is diagonalizable. I know it is correct if $A$ is diagonalizable. I want more general conditions.